# Instructing browser cache to ignore certain URL params

Tags: caching, iframe, browser-cache

I want the two iframes

```
 <iframe src="www.URL.com?name=benny&runtime=1231231>
 <iframe src="www.URL.com?name=benny&runtime=757847584>
```

which are loaded at different times to be mapped to the same cached value in the browser. The server has nothing to do with this. Basically, is there a way to have chrome, firefox, etc... cache api ignore certain parameters (in this case 'runtime') when looking up a src.

Passing a separate param or making a separate call for runtime will not work in the use case

Comment: If both `www.URL.com?name=benny&runtime=1231231` and `www.URL.com?name=benny&runtime=757847584` point to identical resources why do need `runtime` parameter in first place? You probably should remove `runtime` parameter from these URLs.

Comment: Leonid it was an example, runtime is not actually the parameter

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You need to either remove parameters with different values from `src` or use `XMLHttpRequest` and blobs to request resource, and remove parameters from request URI using JavaScript. If you will use `XMLHttpRequest` you also need to consider Same-origin policy.

Browser cache key is a combination of HTTP method and URI. Query parameters are a part of an URI. Relevant excerpt from [HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-2):

> The primary cache key consists of the request method and target URI.
> However, since HTTP caches in common use today are typically limited
> to caching responses to GET, many caches simply decline other methods
> and use only the URI as the primary cache key.

For more information check [New Tricks in XMLHttpRequest2 article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) by Eric Bidelman, [XMLHttpRequest page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [Blob Web APIs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [Same-origin policy page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) on MDN.

If you control server that serves your resources you can also adjust it to vary cache entries by certain parameters. For example in ASP.NET MVC you can use `VaryByParam` property of a `OutputCache` attribute. For more information check [Improving Performance with Output Caching article](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) by Microsoft ASP.NET team.

Comment: solution is to change the ? to a # since the cache ignores everything that follows a cache

Comment: `?` indicates beginning of a query component of a URI. `#` indicates beginning of a fragment component. Strictly speaking, browser HTTP Cache doesn't ignore fragment, rather browser doesn't send it. Query and fragment are different things and exist for different purpose. To understand whether fragments are appropriate in your case you can check [query](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-23) and [fragment](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-24) sections of a URI specification.